# Proving invalidity of an argument.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have a problem in proving invalid the following argument:

**Horses and cows are mammals.Some animals are mammals.Some animals are not mammals.Therefore all horses are animals.**

If we translate it into the logical notation then we have :

The premises are :

$(\forall x)(Hx \lor Cx \rightarrow Mx)$.

$(\exists x)(Ax \land Mx)$

$(\exists x)(Ax  \land \sim Mx)$

The conclusion is :

$(\forall x)(Hx \rightarrow Ax)$.

Where $Ax$ is means $x$ is an animal, $Hx$ means $x$ is a horse, $Cx$ means $x$ is a cow, $Mx$ means $x$ is a Mammal.

I have to show it is an invalid argument.But *the 2nd and 3rd premises are like contradictory to the conclusion part.*

As per I know if I can show a truthvalue assignment for which the conclusion is false still the premises are true,then the argument will be invalid.
But I am unable to find such a truthvalue assignment, **looking for a  help.** Thanks.

Comment: From your premises, do you know that *all* mammals are animals? :-)

Comment: Yes, it helped me to get the flaw.

Answer (score 2):

Red cars and red trucks are red. Some baloons are red. Some baloons are not red. Therefore, all red cars are baloons.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show that it's valid for there to be a horse that is not an animal.

So take $y$ such that $Hy$ is true and $Ay$ is false. Note how this doesn't interfere with the second or third premise.

---

To get the full truth values, consider a universe $\{x,y,z\}$ such that
$$
Mx, My, Ax, Az, Hy\quad \text{are true}
$$
and
$$
Cx, Cy, Cz, Hx, Hz, Ay, Mz\quad \text{are false}.
$$
Then verify that all premises hold and the conclusion fails.

Comment: Yes, I have taken that, but I can't find the truth values such that the premises are true.

Comment: @HirenGarai Well by the first premise you must have $My$ is true. Then you can have $Cy$ be either true or false. This doesn't interfere with the 2nd or 3rd premise because those just guarantee the existence of some $x$ and some $z$ such that $Ax$ and $Mx$ are true and $Az$ is true and $Mz$ is false. So overall you can take your "universe" to be $\{x,z,y\}$ such that $Hy, Ax, Az, Mx, My$ are true and all others are false.

Comment: I am ok with your answer .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer sir !!! Now its ok.